# How to run Swagger Spring Application using Jetty on Docker

Tags: linux, maven, docker, jetty, swagger

I have a swagger spring app which is running on my windows machine using jetty.

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-spring</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>swagger-spring</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
               <!--  <configuration>
                   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/TestApp</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopPort>8079</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>stopit</stopKey>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>8002</port>
                        <idleTimeout>60000</idleTimeout>
                    </httpConnector>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--SpringFox dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <jetty-version>9.2.15.v20160210</jetty-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.7.21</slf4j-version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
        <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
        <springfox-version>2.4.0</springfox-version>
        <jackson-version>2.4.5</jackson-version>
        <spring-version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Maven** :

```
mvn clean install => It's creating a jar file inside my target folder
mvn:jetty run => Jetty running and I can access the application successfully using localhost:8002/TestApp/swagger-ui.html#/ path on browser.
```

Now I want to run this application using Docker on linux machine. Already I have docker images for Oracle-JDK and MAVEN. Now how can I install/use JETTY to run the above application using docker. Please suggest.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very similar [Correct way to deploy WAR files in docker image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252532/correct-way-to-deploy-war-files-in-docker-image)

Comment: I have jar file inside target folder.

Comment: Any solution on this ?