# Google Cloud Manage Tomcat Service

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

Does google cloud or aws provide manage Apache tomcat which just take war file and do auto-scaling based on load increase and decrease ? not compute engine. I dont want to create VM. this should be manage by manage service.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine can directly take and run a WAR file - just use the [appcfg](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/uploadinganapp#using_appcfg_alternative) deployment method.

You will have more options if you package with docker, as this then provides an image type that can be run in many places (Multilpe GCP, AWS and Azure options, on-prem Kubernetes, etc). This can even be as simple as building a dockerfile that just copies the WAR into a jetty image:

```
FROM jetty:latest
COPY YOUR_WAR.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps
```

It might be better to explode the war though - see discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252532/correct-way-to-deploy-war-files-in-docker-image)

Answer (score -1):

AWS provide ** [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html) **

> > The AWS Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat platform is a set of environment configurations for Java web applications that can run in a Tomcat web container. Each configuration corresponds to a major version of Tomcat, like Java 8 with Tomcat 8.
> >
> > Platform-specific configuration options are available in the AWS Management Console for modifying the configuration of a running environment. To avoid losing your environment's configuration when you terminate it, you can use saved configurations to save your settings and later apply them to another environment.
> >
> > To save settings in your source code, you can include configuration files. Settings in configuration files are applied every time you create an environment or deploy your application. You can also use configuration files to install packages, run scripts, and perform other instance customization operations during deployments.

It also provide [autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-autoscaling-triggers.html)

> > The Auto Scaling group in your Elastic Beanstalk environment uses two Amazon CloudWatch alarms to trigger scaling operations. The default triggers scale when the average outbound network traffic from each instance is higher than 6 MB or lower than 2 MB over a period of five minutes. To use Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling effectively, configure triggers that are appropriate for your application, instance type, and service requirements. You can scale based on several statistics including latency, disk I/O, CPU utilization, and request count.